# SQLite searching so slowly

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

this is my code to search from SQLite database:

```
flResults.Controls.Clear()
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        Dim Querytxt As String = "Select * from trancebeats Where Cat LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR  Title LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Artist LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Album LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Year LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Genre LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Publisher LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Site LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' Group By Album Order By Album"
        Dim Adp As SQLiteDataAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter
        Dim Cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand
        Dim TableSRC As New DataTable
        TableSRC.Rows.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer
    With Cmd
        .CommandText = Querytxt
        .Connection = con
    End With

    With Adp
        .SelectCommand = Cmd
        .Fill(TableSRC)
    End With

    If TableSRC.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lblResultsFound.Text = TableSRC.Rows.Count & "  Results founds"
        For i = 0 To TableSRC.Rows.Count - 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            Dim pic As New PictureBox
            Dim lblArtist As New Label
            Dim lblAlbum As New Label
            Dim lblLabel As New Label
            Dim lblCat As New Label
            Dim fl As New Panel
            pic.Size = New Size(75, 75)
            pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            pic.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            pic.Tag = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cat")
            pic.Name = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cat") & "pic"
            pic.Location = New Point(7, 7)
            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cover")) Then
                    Dim xx As Image
                    Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cover"))
                        xx = Image.FromStream(str)
                    End Using
                    pic.Image = xx
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            lblAlbum.AutoEllipsis = True
            lblArtist.AutoEllipsis = True
            lblLabel.AutoEllipsis = True
            lblCat.AutoEllipsis = True
            lblAlbum.AutoSize = False
            lblArtist.AutoSize = False
            lblLabel.AutoSize = False
            lblCat.AutoSize = False
            lblAlbum.Size = New Size(100, 15)
            lblArtist.Size = New Size(100, 15)
            lblLabel.Size = New Size(100, 15)
            lblCat.Size = New Size(100, 15)
            lblAlbum.Text = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Artist")
            lblArtist.Text = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Album")
            lblLabel.Text = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Publisher")
            lblCat.Text = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cat")
            fl.Size = New Size(200, 95)
            fl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue
            fl.Controls.Add(pic)
            fl.Controls.Add(lblArtist)
            fl.Controls.Add(lblAlbum)
            fl.Controls.Add(lblLabel)
            fl.Controls.Add(lblCat)
            fl.Name = TableSRC.Rows(i)("Cat") & "fl"
            AddHandler pic.Click, AddressOf CatClick
            lblArtist.Location = New Point(87, 12)
            lblAlbum.Location = New Point(87, 30)
            lblLabel.Location = New Point(87, 66)
            lblCat.Location = New Point(87, 48)
            AddHandler fl.Click, AddressOf flClick
            AddHandler lblArtist.Click, AddressOf flClick1
            AddHandler lblAlbum.Click, AddressOf flClick1
            AddHandler lblLabel.Click, AddressOf flClick1
            AddHandler lblCat.Click, AddressOf flClick1

            flResults.Controls.Add(fl)
        Next
    Else
        Dim lblNothing As New Label
        lblNothing.Text = "No Results Found!!"
        lblNothing.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        flResults.Controls.Add(lblNothing)
    End If
```

I have more than 5000 rows

when I make a search it takes time to put the results....

is my code wrong or I have to change the way to search???

and when it show me the results ... for example it will show 100 results....I have to wait till it finish showing the results then I can find what I'm searching.....

Comment: what is the differnce between 'LIKE' & 'MATCH' in SQLite???

Answer (score 2):

All those wildcards will take some time to search, even on a small recordset, since each involves a full table scan.

Speeding SQL queries often involves indexing the relevant columns.  Indexed columns can be searched *much* more quickly than non-indexed columns.  Having a wildcard at the beginning of the search term will negate the benefit you'd get from indexing, though.

To gain the benefits of indexing, you could store each column twice, once with the string reversed, index all the columns, and search for `" ... somefield LIKE 'term%' OR somefield_reversed LIKE 'term_reversed%' ... "`  That's a lot of complexity to add for the sake of this one query, though; I'd only do it if it's vital that this one query be very quick.

There are other (probably better) options available to you -- SQLite has a FTS (full text search) extension you might want to look into:  http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: @Brad thanks for the answer ..... I installed Winamp Player... and I liked the database and the way it search for the music but it soo heavy... I tried to open his database with Excel and I saw that he has more columns than mine.... how does it work and search quickly??.....
and in Winamp when you press any key in search bar it search automatically .... I liked that more

Answer (score 0):

Why not just specify a column on your query, friend?

Perhaps place a Combobox on your form with all the Columns you have on a table, then whenever the user searches, the program runs a query whose table is based on the Combobox the user selected

Example:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

          Combobox1.Items.Add("Cat")
          Combobox1.Items.Add("Title")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     Dim Querytxt As String = "Select * from trancebeats Where " & _
     combobox1.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & _
     "%' Group By Album Order By Album"

     End Sub
```

In here, you can let the user just specify which column the program should look for the data in.

Comment: thats what I made first .... but then I saw that I must specify the where I must search .... and then I made this to search more quickly and don't specify where to search...but when searching in the table it takes more time than specify the column

Comment: ..I'm sorry, I didn't get any of that. What do you mean?

Comment: I made it as you say at the first but when I want to search I most choose where I most search and I have another people working with this application it will be more diffecult....so I made the search event to search in all the table without choosing the column...thanks again for your answer

Comment: How will it be difficult for other people in your team?

Comment: well if they want to search they most specify where to search....
for example...my application is about music and I have more than 5000 songs and every song is one row in the table and the table has 10 columns...I can't make a combobox for 10 columns and when they search they will not remeber to choose where to search and they told me to change it